# Unordered list CSS issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have inherited a site developed in Expression Engine and I'm noticing a couple problems. On the home page http://trinidad.myguardiangroup.com/ there is an unordered list on the right and it works when resizing, but for some reason on some laptops (pc laptop using google chrome) the list is not fitting correctly (couple icons not showing). I have tried to go through the CSS and I found this;

```
/* Thumbnail Tray
----------------------------*/
 #thumb-tray {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:3;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    padding-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding-top:35px;
    height:100%;
    width:110px;
    text-align:center;
}
#thumb-back, #thumb-forward {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:5;
    bottom:42px;
    height:108px;
    width:40px;
}
#thumb-back {
    left:0;
    background: url('../img/thumb-back.png') no-repeat center center;
}
#thumb-forward {
    right:0;
    background:url('../img/thumb-forward.png') no-repeat center center;
}
#thumb-back:hover, #thumb-forward:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color:rgba(256, 256, 256, 0.1);
}
#thumb-back:hover {
    border-right:1px solid rgba(256, 256, 256, 0.2);
}
#thumb-forward:hover {
    border-left:1px solid rgba(256, 256, 256, 0.2);
}
ul#thumb-list {
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    left:0px;
    padding:0 0px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
ul#thumb-list li {
    list-style:none;
    display:inline-block;
    height: 55px;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow:visible;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
}
ul#thumb-list li img {
    width:45px;
    height:auto;
    opacity:0.9;
}
ul#thumb-list li.current-thumb img, ul#thumb-list li:hover img {
    opacity:1;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
}
ul#thumb-list li:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

But nothing I do to that affects the list at all...All I would want to do is to shrink the size of the list so that it fits properly.

If any of you see a more efficient way of dealing with this problem I am all ears and willing to learn.

```
<ul id="demo-block">
   <li>
      <div id="slidecaption"></div>
      <div id="thumb-tray" class="load-item">
         <div id="homeimage0" class="show0"><img src="http://myguardiangroup.com/images/hometext/life-home.png"class="homeimagesize"></div>
         <div id="homeimage1" class="show1"><img src="http://myguardiangroup.com/images/hometext/health-home.png" class="homeimagesize"></div>
         <div id="homeimage2" class="show2"><img src="http://myguardiangroup.com/images/hometext/pensions-home.png" class="homeimagesize"></div>
         <div id="homeimage3" class="show3"><img src="http://myguardiangroup.com/images/hometext/employee-home.png" class="homeimagesize"></div>
         <div id="homeimage4" class="show4"><img src="http://myguardiangroup.com/images/hometext/mutual-home.png" class="homeimagesize"></div>
         <div id="homeimage5" class="show5"><img src="http://myguardiangroup.com/images/hometext/privatewealth-home.png" class="homeimagesize"></div>
         <div id="homeimage6" class="show6"><img src="http://myguardiangroup.com/images/hometext/motor-home.png" class="homeimagesize"></div>
         <div id="homeimage7" class="show7"><img src="http://myguardiangroup.com/images/hometext/marine-home.png" class="homeimagesize"></div>
         <div id="homeimage8" class="show8"><img src="http://myguardiangroup.com/images/hometext/business-home.png" class="homeimagesize"></div>
         <div id="homeimage9" class="show9"><img src="http://myguardiangroup.com/images/hometext/residential-home.png" class="homeimagesize"></div>
         <div id="homeimage10" class="show10"><img src="http://myguardiangroup.com/images/hometext/personalaccident-home.png" class="homeimagesize"></div>
         <div id="homeimage11" class="show11"><img src="http://myguardiangroup.com/images/hometext/travel-home.png" class="homeimagesize"></div>
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can we see the HTML for the list too?

Comment: Sure, I was trying to paste it in. It seems to long to paste in,....am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @JeromeRuiz If you're curious, what I did to format the HTML was to paste it into [an HTML formatter](http://www.freeformatter.com/html-formatter.html), then paste the formatted code into the question, then select all of it and click the "Code Sample {}" button in the formatting toolbar, which indents it all 4 spaces so it shows up formatted as code.

Answer (score 0):

this has nothing to do with the list, the problem is your footer. Its overlapping the content. Fix the positioning of the footer (which has fixed instead of relative positioning) or else add `overflow-y:auto;` to your content div